# I want to update quantity and subtotal in listview c#

Tags: c#, listview

the only updating is the quantity , i also want the subtotal in my listview to be updated when the quantity is updating. Can you help me ? Thank you

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)         
{
    foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(i.SubItems[0].Text) ==txtProduct.Text)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem items in listView1.Items)
            {     
                items.SubItems[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Qty1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(items.SubItems[3].Text))
                items.SubItems[4].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(txtPriceC.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(items.SubItems[3].Text));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of the table]

This is my listview.

The quantity is updating in the listview if i add an item with the same product name, but the subtotal is not. What I want to achieve is when my quantity is updating the subtotal is also updating.

Comment: is there wrong something wrong with the codes?

Comment: Do you know that both the WinForms and WPF and probably a lot of other technologies seem to have `ListViewItem` class? You didn't tell us what GUI library you use. And we have no idea where your subtotal should be. So I am not sure how we can help you without [additional information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i updated the question i added a picture

Comment: If you say that quantity is updated successfully and if `txtPriceC.Text` contains the correct price (**are you sure in that?**), it should work. Otherwise, create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. Recommended reading - http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Despite i don't really get what you want to do as the information in your question is not really clear, I assume that the second foreach loop is not really necessay. Maybe you can post a screenshot of your WinForm (or is it WPF?) and the content of the ListView?

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)  
{
    foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (i.SubItems[0].Text == txtProduct.Text)
        {
            i.SubItems[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Qty1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(i.SubItems[3].Text));
            i.SubItems[4].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(i.SubItems[2].Text) * Convert.ToInt32(i.SubItems[3].Text));                                         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it seems we need more information. What should be the main goal of your program? You have to be precise in your explanation. I guess the answer is simple, but without a good explanation I am lost here :)

Comment: we are doing an ordering system . and i have an add to cart button . in add to cart button the values Product name , price , quantity and subtotal. subtotal is computed price * quantity . and it will add in listview . And when i add a new value with the same product name it will only add the quantity and will not add new row. and i want to happen is when the quantity is updated in listview the subtotal will also be updated

Comment: I updated the code in my answer post. If I guessed right, you want the subtotal of the information stored in `i.SubItems[2]` (on your picture column PRICE) and multiply that with the `i.SubItems[3]` (column QTY) and store the result in `i.SubItems[4].Text`. Therefore the second foreach loop is unnecessary.

Comment: still the only updating is the quantity , subtotal is still the same.

Comment: can you provide the project as a download?